# javascript "strict" and instantiating global modules

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'd like to `"use strict";` mode in javascript but have some problems with strict warnings.
I have a "widget", e.g.:

```
var Widget = function () { /* ... */ }
```

Before I was using it like this (inside a module):

```
(function () {
    var w1 = new Widget();
}());
```

when I add `"use strict";` to this context I get a warning that `"Widget"` is not defined:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var w1 = new Widget();      // <- warning here
}());
```

What is the proper way of doing this?

Should I define my "widgets" differently?

Comment: Thanks @Teemu. If you add this as a response I can accept it to resolve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In strict mode you can't accidentally create global variables. Trying to do so will throw a reference error, as you've noticed. Hence you need to name an object, which has `Widget` assigned:

```
window.Widget = function () { /* ... */ }
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var w1 = new window.Widget();
}());
```

More info: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) , [www.nczonline.net](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/13/its-time-to-start-using-javascript-strict-mode/)

Comment: btw, I don't think you need `var` when declaring window.Widget (it throws an error).